# VueJS and a static JSON endpoint without IDs

Tags: json, vue.js, endpoint

So I'm trying to create a VueJS application, and I was given a set of JSON objects that are retrievable through a `.json` endpoint.

I'll call them `People`. So I get an array of people in `this.people` after using VueResource.

I'm able to iterate and get all the name displayed on the side, however, since its not an API nor has unique IDs minus their array indexes, I am having trouble trying to narrow down each object and create a single `Person` view page.

Hence if it was a normal api, I could do '`/people/:id`', but I can't. I'm also wondering if I may have stored the `Prop/Component` correctly.

Comment: The json contains all the information you need for each person?

Comment: Correct, I'm having trouble trying to isolate them to get individual views in VueJs

Comment: Are you using VueRouter or just trying to show a details page?

Comment: Using VueRouter, so I have a People component then PeopleDetails component, and ultimately would like to click on the name to display the rest of their details.

Comment: In that case you can just pass the person selected as a property to the PeopleDetails component as part of the `params` object in VueRouter.

Comment: Thanks! I've been going through the docs and tutorials, and felt like it may be something like that, but havent been sure. I will try that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a quick example of how this might work with the Star Wars API.

```
const Loading = {
  template: `<h1>Loading...</h1>`
};

const People = {
  props: ["people"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>People</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="person in people">
          <router-link :to='{name: "person", params:{person: person}}'>{{person.name}}</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
};

const PersonDetails = {
  props: ["person"],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>{{person.name}}</h1>
      <div>Height: {{person.height}}</div>
      <div>Mass: {{person.mass}}</div>
      <div>Hair Color: {{person.hair_color}}</div>
      <br/>
      <router-link to="people">Back to people</router-link>
    </div>
  `
};

const routes = [
  { path:"/", component: Loading},
  { path: "/people", name: "people", component: People},
  { path: "/person", name: "person", component: PersonDetails, props: true},
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  data:{
    people:[]
  },
  mounted(){
    this.$axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.people = response.data.results
        this.$router.push("people")
      })
  }
});
```

Here is the working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/mmwXJp?editors=1010).

Comment: This has been a HUGE help! thank you!  Literally a lifesaver.  I've been then trying to break it into components, a router file, etc. and it seems to work, but its having trouble with  `<router-link :to="{ name: 'person', params: {person}}">{{person.name}}</router-link>`  It will throw: `Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'regex' of undefined" ` and say there is no person route when there is.

Comment: @LK Do you have a pen/fiddle or something where I can see your code? Preferably working and demonstrating the error?

Comment: ah sorry meant  `<router-link :to="{ name: 'person', params: {person: person}}">{{person.name}}</router-link>`

Comment: [CodePen Ex.](https://codepen.io/lko/pen/bWrrwq?editors=0110)  I put just all the vue and js files for viewing in the JS pen window

Comment: @LK it looks like your router definition is a little bit off. new VueRouter() takes an object and one of the properties of that is the `routes` property. In the code of my answer you can see, `new VueRouter({routes})` which could also be `new VueRouter({routes: routes})`. Yours looks like you are passing route objects instead.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that did it.   Also getting a warning: `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "people"`     This is my first VueJS project and first time being not in the backend for sometime, lol so thank you for guiding me. I couldn't find many people who've worked it

Comment: You're getting that warning because you are fetching the `people` in **People.vue**, but `people` is also defined in the main Vue and passed as a property to **People.vue**. You should probably leave the data fetching in the main Vue. The component will get it passed in.

Comment: That got it working -- Have you come across anything where the links will not render?   Its not throwing any errors, just clicking the names renders nothing.  Is it where `<router-view>` goes that is causing this?

Comment: @LK  If you can throw your code up on github or similar I can clone the repo and see whats up.

Comment: @LK Sent a pull request.

Comment: thank you so much. If you were in Chicago, I'd buy you several beers.